# Spawn shell and source in one command

Tags: zsh

I have sciprt that launches my development environment with multiple tmux tiles. I want to spawn a shell that sources my environment so I dont have to source it myself.

I usually do the following each time I open the tmux tile:

```sh
source env/bin/activate
```

I spawn my shell with `$SHELL`, I use `zsh`. I see that `bash` has the `--init-file` flag which sources a file, this also does not load the bashrc. I guess thats close but not good enough.

I am looking for something like this `$SHELL --source ~/env/bin/activate`. Or any workarounds also help

Comment: I think you could do this by having your regular `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` or whatever you're using check for an environment variable, then source the environment file you want. Or see if there's something else to check, like current directory. Or wrap your shell in a script that does the sourcing before running the actual shell.

Comment: perhaps a file that sources .zshrc and my env, then use the --init-file flag to source that file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible; Your best bet is to implement a workaround in your own `.zshenv` file, e.g.,

```
if [[ test -e "$MY_INIT_SCRIPT_675" ]] ; then
 source "$MY_INIT_SCRIPT_675"
fi
```